# Image Segmentation and Classification with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, image-segmentation

I'm new to using Google Earth Engine and I obtained the following code from Medium and tried to update it with the AOI and training data for my specific area. I am trying to classify landcover for an AOI and then export this to csv using CORINE landuse categories

The issue seems to be with the classification as when I run the code it just hangs while the other maps seem to be produced correctly.  I've been trying to spot the problem but so far I haven't made any progress.

```
var train_points = Peat_Bogs
        .merge(Coniferous_Forest) 
        .merge(ContinuousUrban) 
        .merge(DiscontinuousUrban)
        .merge(DumpSites)
        .merge(IndustrialAreas)
        .merge(InlandMarshes)
        .merge(MineralExtraction)
        .merge(MixedForest)
        .merge(MoorsandHeathlands)
        .merge(NaturalGrasslands)
        .merge(RoadandRail)
        .merge(Marine)
        .merge(Waterbody)
        .merge(Sports_Facilities)
        .merge(SaltMarshes)
        .merge(Sparsely_Vegetated_Area)
        .merge(BurntAreas)
        .merge(Traditional_Woodland_Schrub)
        .merge(Pastureland)
        .merge(BroadLeaf_Forest)
        .merge(Beaches_Dunes_and_Sand)
        .merge(Ports_Areas)
        .merge(ConstructionSites)
        .merge(Non_irrigated_arable_land)
        .merge(LandOccupiedbyAgricultural)
        .merge(CoastalLagoons)



var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA').filter(ee.Filter.date('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(AOI).sort('CLOUD_COVER').first();
                  // Sort by scene cloudiness, ascending.
                  
                  // Get the first (least cloudy) scene.
                 
  

// Compute cloud score.
var cloudScore = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(dataset).select('cloud');


// Mask the input for clouds.  Compute the min of the input mask to mask
// pixels where any band is masked.  Combine that with the cloud mask.
var Training_Image1 = dataset.updateMask(dataset.mask().reduce('min').and(cloudScore.lte(50)));
                  
                  
var img = Training_Image1.clip(AOI);
var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0, 
  bands:"B3,B2,B1"
};
Map.centerObject(AOI);
Map.addLayer(img);

var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(["B4", "B3"]).rename('NDVI')

Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-1, max:0.8, palette: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green"]}, "NDVI")
//Map.addLayer(ndvi.gt([0.03, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12, 0.15,0.18,0.21,0.24,0.27,0.30,0.33,0.35,0.38,0.41,0.44,0.47,0.50,0.53,0.56,0.59,0.62,0.]).reduce('sum'), {min:0, max: 4, palette: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkgreen"]}, "NDVI steps")
//Map.addLayer(ndvi.gt().reduce('sum'), {min:0, max: 26, palette: palette}, "NDVI steps")

var ndviGradient = ndvi.gradient().pow(2).reduce('sum').sqrt().rename('NDVI_GRAD')
Map.addLayer(ndviGradient, {min:0, max:0.01}, "NDVI gradient")

// Compute entropy and display.
var square = ee.Kernel.square({radius: 4});


var entropy = img.select('B4').toByte().entropy(square);
Map.addLayer(entropy);

var glcm = img.select('B4').toByte().glcmTexture({size: 4});
print(glcm)
var contrast = glcm.select('B4_contrast');
//Map.addLayer(contrast, {min: 0, max: 1500, palette: ['0000CC', 'CC0000']}, 'contrast');
var asm = glcm.select('B4_asm');
//Map.addLayer(asm, {}, 'asm');


var bands = ['B3', 'B2', 'B1', 'B4'];
var FullImage = img.select(bands).float().divide(255);


// Segmentation -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(35);

var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: FullImage, 
  compactness: 0,
  connectivity: 4,
  neighborhoodSize: 128,
  size: 20,
  seeds: seeds
})



var clusters_snic = snic.select("clusters")

var vectors = clusters_snic.reduceToVectors({
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  geometry: AOI,
});


var empty = ee.Image().byte();


var outline = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: vectors,
  color: 1,
  width: 1
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'segments');



// Select train polygons from points -------------------------------------------------------

//var FullImage = FullImage.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndviGradient)
                         //.addBands(glcm.select(['B4_contrast','B4_asm',"B4_corr"]).float())
                         //.addBands(entropy);
                         

var FullImage = FullImage.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndviGradient);

var train_polys = vectors.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var point = feat.geometry();
  


  var mappedPolys = train_points.map(function(poly){
    var cls = poly.get("LC")
    var intersects = poly.intersects(point, ee.ErrorMargin(1));
    var property = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(intersects, 'TRUE', 'FALSE'));
    return feat.set('belongsTo',  property).set('LC', cls);
  });
  return mappedPolys;
}).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.neq('belongsTo', 'FALSE'));




//extract features from train polygons --------------------------------------------- 

var train_areas = train_polys
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['LC'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).rename('LC').toInt();



// Extract features from image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var predict_image = vectors
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['label'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).rename('id').toInt();


FullImage = FullImage.addBands(predict_image)


var FullImage_mean = FullImage.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  labelBand: 'id'
});


var FullImage_std = FullImage.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  labelBand: 'id'
});



var FullImage_median = FullImage.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  labelBand: 'id'
});


var FullImage_area = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(FullImage.select('id')).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.sum(), 'id')
var FullImage_sizes = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().addBands(FullImage.select('id')).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.minMax(), 'id')
var FullImage_width = FullImage_sizes.select('longitude_max').subtract(FullImage_sizes.select('longitude_min')).rename('width')
var FullImage_height = FullImage_sizes.select('latitude_max').subtract(FullImage_sizes.select('latitude_min')).rename('height')


// join features in an image

var Pred_bands = ee.Image.cat([
  FullImage_mean,
  FullImage_std,
  FullImage_median,
  FullImage_area,
  FullImage_width,
  FullImage_height
]).float();



var clip_Image = Pred_bands.clip(train_polys)



train_areas = train_areas.addBands(clip_Image)

var predictionBands = Pred_bands.bandNames();


var classifierTraining = train_areas.select(predictionBands).sampleRegions({collection: train_polys, properties: ['LC'], scale: 30 });

var RF = ee.Classifier.randomForest(30).train({features:classifierTraining, classProperty:'LC', inputProperties: predictionBands});


var classified_RF = Pred_bands.select(predictionBands).classify(RF);



//var vis_RF = {min: 0, max: 4,
//palette: [ 'blue' //0
//,'red' //1
//,'orange' //2
//,'green' //3
//,'yellow']//4
//}
//Map.addLayer(classified_RF,vis_RF,"OBIA_RF");

Map.addLayer(classified_RF);
```

Please see link to code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2F454262%2FTest%3APixel_Based%2FTest_OBI

Comment: Do you get thrown an error message or does your runtime time-out? If the latter, might need to export the classified image out of the cloud or to your assets (will receive longer runtime). Could not access your script.

Comment: Thanks! I've added code above. I get an error code saying "Layer 6: Layer error: User memory limit exceeded".  I'll try export the output as you suggested

Comment: Exporting the image didn't work. I got an error code saying "Error: Image.classify: Classification request exceeds size limit".   I'd appreciate any further suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer, but judging by the error message, you have too many training points or a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the training points and adding a new, much smaller training dataset the script worked.